# Cannot debug C++ in visual studio code on Mac. Launch.json does not execute program in terminal

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code

I am new to Visual Studio Code. I am trying to debug a simple C++ code.
I edited my `launch.json` to be able to debug the app like this:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(lldb) Launch", 
            "type": "cppdbg",  
            "request": "launch",      
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/Calculator",   
            "args": [],   
            "stopAtEntry": false,  
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",  
            "environment": [],  
            "externalConsole": true,  
            "MIMode": "lldb"            
        }        
    ]
}
```

When I start debugging, the terminal is opened in the correct folder but the program is not executed. So the Visual Code does not stop in the breakpoints I want to check in the program.

In my task.json I have the following code:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Echo vars",
            "command": "echo",
            "args": [
                "${env:USERNAME}",
                "workspaceFolder = ${workspaceFolder}"
            ],
            "type": "shell",
            "problemMatcher": []
        },
        {
            "label": "build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++ -g Calculator.cpp -o Calculator",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "problemMatcher": "$gcc"
        }
    ]
}
```

Can anybody help me on this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you built your code with debug symbols?

Comment: Hi Alan, thanks for answering. I am afraid I do not know what you mean with "debug symbols". Can you explain me that in more detail please?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments: if your Calculator.cpp is not compiled with debug symbols ie. g++ called without -g flag, you will not be able to debug it.

Hence, add to your launch.json a `prelaunchTask` entry which will make sure your build task which is compiling your source with debug symbols is always executed prior to launching the debugger.

```
"environment": [],  
"externalConsole": true,  
"MIMode": "lldb",      
"preLaunchTask": "build"
```

edit your launch.json to add debugger log output to your project:

```
"logging": { "engineLogging": true, "trace": false, "traceResponse": false }
```

Comment: I added all that. Besides in my task.json I have the following sentence: "command": "g++ -g Calculator.cpp -o Calculator", so I guess I am compiling with debug symbols as you suggested. I followed different tutorial and I do not know what is wrong with may Mac. I guess I will try to reinstall VSCode again

Comment: do you see in VSC that the command `g++ -g Calculator.cpp -o Calculator` is executed before your program is launched?

Comment: Hi pero_hero. Thanks for answering. Yes, the command is being executed before my program is launched. Actually, to be sure of that I deleted the executable file after pressing the Start Debugging button. And the command is perfectly executed. Calculator executable file is correctly created.

Comment: In the debug console i always get this message: "Warning: Debuggee TargetArchitecture not detected, assuming x86_64."

Comment: I have this warning message as well and it is working. can you try to add a logging output of the debugger to your project, as shown in the updated answer and add the first part of it to the OP? I would also set stopAtEntry to true.

Comment: I put stopAtEntry = true. Nothing changed. It is so strange that the terminal is opened but the Calculator.exe file is not executed. I am not sure how to add a logging out. I searched on google and what i did is: 1) "cmd + shift + P" 2) Select "Developer: Set the log level" 3) Chose option "Debug"

Comment: You are working on a Mac, right? My current MacOs version is Catalina 10.15.3.

Comment: Actually, something I did not mention is that the terminal is automatically opened but not i the correct folder. It is opened in the last folder used.

Comment: yes, i am also using a mac with mojave os 10.14.6. your launch.json and tasks.json file are in the `.vscode` folder in your project? you enable further logs by adding the line `"logging": { "engineLogging": true, "trace": false, "traceResponse": false }`to your launch.json file.

Comment: Hi @pero_hero. I added "engineLogging":true in the launch.json file. Visual Studio Code did not recognize the other two elements (neither "trace" nor "traceResponse") so I could not add them.

Comment: The debug console output is the following:

Comment: 1: (1126) LaunchOptions<LocalLaunchOptions xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/MDDDebuggerOptions/2014'
1: (1208) LaunchOptions  ExePath='/Users/jcesano/Desktop/cppcon/Calculator'
1: (1208) LaunchOptions  WorkingDirectory='/Users/jcesano/Desktop/cppcon'
1: (1208) LaunchOptions  ExeArguments=''
1: (1209) LaunchOptions  MIMode='lldb'
1: (1215) LaunchOptions  MIDebuggerPath='/Users/jcesano/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.cpptools-0.27.0-insiders3/debugAdapters/lldb-mi/bin/lldb-mi'
1: (1216) LaunchOptions  WaitDynamicLibLoad='false'
1: (1221) LaunchOptions  ExternalConsole='true'

Comment: 1: (1221) LaunchOptions>
1: (1226) LaunchOptions</LocalLaunchOptions>
1: (1831) Starting: "/Users/jcesano/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.cpptools-0.27.0-insiders3/debugAdapters/lldb-mi/bin/lldb-mi" --interpreter=mi
1: (1935) DebuggerPid=11408
1: (2995) ->(gdb)
1: (3062) <-1001-interpreter-exec console "version"
1: (3082) ->~"lldb-1100.0.30.12\nApple Swift version 5.1.3 (swiftlang-1100.0.282.1 clang-1100.0.33.15)\n"
1: (3091) ->1001^done1: (3094) ->(gdb)
1: (3098) 1001: elapsed time 41
1: (3109) <-1002-gdb-set auto-solib-add on
1: (3113) ->1002^done
1: (3114) ->(gdb)

Comment: 1: (3116) 1002: elapsed time 7
1: (3119) <-1003-gdb-set solib-search-path "/Users/jcesano/Desktop/cppcon:"
1: (3125) ->1003^done
1: (3125) 1003: elapsed time 5
1: (3126) <-1004-environment-cd /Users/jcesano/Desktop/cppcon
1: (3131) ->(gdb)
1: (3146) ->1004^done,path="/Users/jcesano/Desktop/cppcon"
1: (3150) ->(gdb)
1: (3158) 1004: elapsed time 31
1: (3159) <-1005-gdb-set new-console on
1: (3161) ->1005^done
1: (3161) 1005: elapsed time 2
1: (3161) <-1006-file-exec-and-symbols /Users/jcesano/Desktop/cppcon/Calculator

Comment: 1: (3171) ->(gdb)
1: (4803) ->1006^done
1: (4803) 1006: elapsed time 1642
1: (4804) <-1007-interpreter-exec console "platform status"
1: (4806) ->(gdb)
1: (4811) ->=library-loaded,id="/Users/jcesano/Desktop/cppcon/Calculator",target-name="/Users/jcesano/Desktop/cppcon/Calculator",host-name="/Users/jcesano/Desktop/cppcon/Calculator",symbols-loaded="1",symbols-path="/Users/jcesano/Desktop/cppcon/Calculator.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/Calculator",loaded_addr="-",size="8192"
1: (4821) ->~"  Platform: host\n    Triple: x86_64-apple-macosx\nOS Version: 10.15.3 (19D76)\n    Kernel: Darwin Ker

Comment: Darwin Kernel Version 19.3.0: Thu Jan  9 20:58:23 PST 2020; root:xnu-6153.81.5~1/RELEASE_X86_64\n  Hostname: 127.0.0.1\nWorkingDir: /Users/jcesano/Desktop/cppcon\n"
1: (4824) ->1007^done
1: (4824) ->(gdb)
1: (4824) 1007: elapsed time 20
1: (4826) <-1008-break-insert -f main
1: (4910) ->1008^done,bkpt={number="1",type="breakpoint",disp="keep",enabled="y",addr="0x0000000100000a96",func="main",file="Calculator.cpp",fullname="/Users/jcesano/Desktop/cppcon/Calculator.cpp",line="16",pending=["main"],times="0",original-location="main"}
1: (4913) ->(gdb)
1: (4913) ->=breakpoint-modified,bkpt=

Comment: {number="1",type="breakpoint",disp="keep",enabled="y",addr="0x0000000100000a96",func="main",file="Calculator.cpp",fullname="/Users/jcesano/Desktop/cppcon/Calculator.cpp",line="16",pending=["main"],times="0",original-location="main"}
1: (4913) ->(gdb)
1: (4926) 1008: elapsed time 99
1: (4947) Send Event AD7EngineCreateEvent
1: (4954) Send Event AD7ProgramCreateEvent
1: (5134) <-1009-break-insert -f calculator.cpp:17
1: (5140) ->1009^done,bkpt={number="2",type="breakpoint",disp="keep",enabled="y",addr="0xffffffffffffffff",func="??",file="??",fullname="??/??",line="0",pending=["calculator

Comment: .cpp:17"],times="0",original-location="calculator.cpp:17"}
1: (5141) 1009: elapsed time 6
1: (5141) ->(gdb)
1: (5142) ->=breakpoint-modified,bkpt={number="2",type="breakpoint",disp="keep",enabled="y",addr="0xffffffffffffffff",func="??",file="??",fullname="??/??",line="0",pending=["calculator.cpp:17"],times="0",original-location="calculator.cpp:17"}
1: (5142) ->(gdb)
1: (5164) Send Event AD7BreakpointErrorEvent
1: (5334) Send Event AD7LoadCompleteEvent
Warning: Debuggee TargetArchitecture not detected, assuming x86_64.
1: (5349) <-1010-exec-run

Comment: THAT IS ALL!!! I Hope it has some useful information. to be honest I did not find anything. But I am very new into Visual Studio Code

Comment: Thanks in advanced

Comment: does this configuration stop on the first line of the main function? you seem to be setting a breakpoint in a file `calculator.cpp` in line 17, but your file is actually called `Calculator.cpp`? Can you remove all your breakpoints and create new on in `Calculator.cpp`?

Comment: I changed the name of the file from calculator.cpp to Caculator.cpp and set the breakpoint again in line 17. But the problem is still there. The terminal is opened but program is not being executed.